# masterpage with usercontrol problem

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, user-controls

I have a masterpage and 2 `usercontrols(A.ascx & B.ascx)` on this masterpage. In these one of them `usercontrol(A.ascx)` have another `usercontrol(C.ascx)`. And I use this masterpage on `default.aspx` page. On this `Default.aspx` page we have one more usercontrol i.e. `(D.ascx).`

Now my problem is that I want to changeover the css class of `C.ascx` usercontrol on changing in `D.ascx.` Or how to call and access any function of `c.ascx` in user control `d.ascx.`

Hence this `d.ascx` in on `default.aspx` page and `c.ascx` is in masterpage usercontrol's usercontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserControl B = (UserControl)this.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.FindControl("B1");   
B.GetType().GetMethod("check").Invoke(B,null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below might help you.

```
 UserControl C = (UserControl)this.NamingContainer.FindControl("A").FindControl("C");
```

You can access any method of user control c by its Object"

Comment: I did but it did't work, i make a function in c.ascx and by using this method i didn't call it.